Combination of `display: grid` And `<details>` Breaks Overflow?
I have a layout where I apply display: grid to the <body> element. Inside this layout, I have a <details> elements containing a wrapper with a long rectangle. I want the wrapper to have horizontal scrolling using overflow-x: scroll, which works fine without the grid layout. It also works fine without the <details> element. However, when I have both, display: grid on the body and the <details> element, the wrapper becomes as long as the rectangle.


body {
  display: grid;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.rect {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red, green);
}
<details>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="rect"></div>
  </div>
</details>



Works similarly with a <pre> tag containing a very long line instead of the wrapper. Also for overflow: hidden instead of scroll.
What could be the reason for this?
EDIT
I found out that grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) on the body removes this behaviour. But still curious, why is <details> specifically triggering this?

no <summary> element !?.

There are a couple of syntax errors in your HTML. What happens if you mend those?

You can put a summary, I just tried to keep it simple. Having a summary doesn't change anything.

This question is similar to: Prevent content from expanding grid items. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To explain my duplicate suggestion above: Adding a min-width: 0 to the details element should resolve the issue.

Adding a min-width: 0 to the details element will resolve the issue. Like so:


body {
  display: grid;
}

details {
  min-width: 0 /*this fixes the issue*/
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.rect {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red, green);
}
<details>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="rect"></div>
  </div>
</details>



Explanation, from this answer, is the following:

By default, a grid item cannot be smaller than the size of its content.
Grid items have an initial size of min-width: auto and min-height: auto.
You can override this behavior by setting grid items to min-width: 0, min-height: 0 or overflow with any value other than visible.

From the spec:
6.6. Automatic Minimum Size of Grid Items

To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for grid items, this specification defines that the auto value of min-width / min-height also applies an automatic minimum size in the specified axis to grid items whose overflow is visible. (The effect is analogous to the automatic minimum size imposed on flex items.)


Thanks for the answer! Do you have an explanation for this behavior? What is the default min-width of  <details>?

@fweth I've updated my answer. The default is auto, afaik.
